# HeaderedContentControl ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Why there is no `HeaderedContentControl ItemsSource` property?

How then can I databind to a list of objects to be represented by `HeaderedContentControl`?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 2):

Because ItemsSource is all about *multiple* pieces of content, and HeaderedContentControl has *one* piece of content.  Put another way, HeaderedContentControl's job is to present a *single* object, so it doesn't need a property whose job is to feed it multiple pieces of content.

Use HeaderedItemsControl instead, or (depending on your requirements) an ItemsControl where the DataTemplate is a HeaderedContentControl.  (Though in the latter case you might as well just use a Panel and multiple elements within the panel -- the HCC isn't really buying you anything.)  HIC's job is to present multiple items under a single header, and it's pretty flexible.  For example, the framework uses HIC as the base class for both TreeViewItem (whose "header" is the item at hand, and whose "items" are the children of that item) and MenuItem (whose "header" is the menu item, and whose "items" are any sub-menu-items, for example in a drop-down or pop-out menu).

Answer (score 1):

There's no ItemsSource property, since it can have only a single child (or two children if you count Header in), just like the class it inherits from - [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx). Use Content property instead.

You can find more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.aspx).

If you want to display list of objects within HeaderedContentControl, then just add ListBox as its Content and fill ListBox with objects.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a [HeaderedItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616578%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

You can find a sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771556%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind the collection to the **Content** property.

HeaderedContentControl by name itself is a collection of ContentControl each with Header.